# Had prepared / Have prepared / Prepared

Tags: tense

I'm writing something and wondering which one is the best choice and why.

The situation is that I'm explaining about a experience of cooking for my parents to one of my friends.

> 1. It was the first time that I'd prepared dinner for my parents.
> 2. It was the first time that I prepared dinner for my parents.
> 3. It was the first time that I've prepared dinner for my parents.

If possible, can I ask the difference?

Comment: The last one is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second would be correct since for the last one, there is conflict in the **tense**. You see, there needs to be **verb tense agreement** or **consistency** in a sentence. Read more on this here:

[Verb Tense Consistency](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/601/04/)

Now your first sentence agrees perfectly in terms of its verbs and tense therefore it is the **correct one**. The second one just says **prepared** but still indicates past tense which is in agreement with was. So it is also **correct**.

Comment: And just to add - there is no difference in meaning between the first two. In this example, Past Simple and Past Perfect mean the same thing.